# Responsive Qt GUI even if threading

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, qcustomplot, responsiveness

So assume you have lots of stuff to draw with a sample time of 10ms, namely 9 charts/graphs (based on qcustomplot library) and a GLWidget. Now all the computation, with which i mean maths, is performed in a separate thread yet instructions like "populate the array of the #1 chart" or "clean the chart" are performed in the GUI thread (clearly at a speed of 10ms).

My problem is that basically, due to the high frequency of the drawing, buttons become unresponsive.

Now my question is:
Is there a way to improve the performance of my code? I would like to avoid to draw every 50ms rather than every 10ms. Could a possible solution be the use of qApp->processEvents(); ? Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: One thing you could do (if you're not doing it already) is render a QImage of the appropriate size in the other thread also.  Then pass the QImage to the main thread, which needs only convert it to a Pixmap and display it.  That might be more efficient (at least in the main thread) than having to do a bunch of drawing commands every 10mS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to draw anything with a speed of 10ms/per sample.. just because an eye is not able to handle this.. you can use (as was mentioned in the comments) 'double buffering' and render everything you need to show on a separate thread and just refresh an image 100 times a second, but again there is no any reasons to keep such high frame rate..

Comment: due to the fact that im acquiring data i need to populate charts/graph.. so you can clearly notice the difference.. slowing down is indeed a solution though

Comment: let's say you got 10 samples within say 50ms.. there is no difference between redrawing once every 50ms or 10 times every 5ms, user hardly will notice any difference

Answer (score 0):

If you want the GUI to be more responsive, call `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` periodically within whatever code is taking up a lot of cpu cycles.  You'll need to `#include <QCoreApplication>` in whatever modules you make the call in.  By the way, this will actually hurt performance because of the extra function calls, but it will make the GUI more responsive, which will probably give the appearance of better performance (ironically).

Comment: is qApp->processEvents() the same?

Comment: I don't know, but with the `qApp` method, every object in which you need to call `processEvents()` needs to have a reference to an instance of  `qApp`.  This means you either have to make it global, or pass it as a constuctor/method argument, neither of which is very clean.  Calling the equivalant static method from `QCoreApplication` requires no reference or pointer to a `qApp`.